# How to use GitHub API to retrieve the latest version of a package?

Tags: github-api, github-package-registry, github-packages

I'm publishing my build artifacts (JARs, WARs) to a [GitHub Packages](https://github.com/features/packages) repository. In the web UI I can easily download any version of the packages, and the latest version is what shows up by default when visiting a package's page.

How can I use the GitHub API to find and download the latest version of a package? I've read through [the documentation on Packages API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/packages), but all I see there is a way to list packages and get details about a specific version. I was hoping there was something like `https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/packages/PACKAGE_TYPE/PACKAGE_NAME/latest` but nothing like that seems to exist.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this as well, so I solved it by using the GitHub Packages REST API to list the package versions and then extracting the tag from the first element in the respose using jq:

```
curl -s \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer <github_token>" \
      -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
      https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/packages/PACKAGE_TYPE/PACKAGE_NAME/versions | jq '[.[] ] | .[0] .metadata .container .tags[0]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Nanor answer, I've achieved it with `gh` cli tool:

```
gh api orgs/$ORG/packages/$PACKAGE_TYPE/$PACKAGE_NAME/versions | jq -r '.[0].name'
```